# AngularFirestoreModule throwing errors Firebase Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, npm, import

I have 2 apps in Angular that need Firebase authentication because of updated read and write rules to auth!=null . I was successful with implementing it to one of the apps that uses Angular 13 and now I wanted to copy the same implementation to my Angular 15 app. I have installed Angular Fire and Firebase module and then wanted to add necessary modules to app.module.ts. Everything goes smoothly untill I add import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

Then I get this errors:

```
ERROR

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentSnapshotExists<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData | undefined'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined` constraint.


ERROR

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:40
    23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
                                              ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


ERROR

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QuerySnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  Types of property 'docs' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>[]'.
      Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
        The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:32
    26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
                                      ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


ERROR

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentChange<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentChange<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'doc.data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:33
    29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
                                       ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { CircleComponent } from './circle/circle.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
// import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';  THROWS THE ERROR
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth'; 
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    CircleComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
```

Output of ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 15.1.6
Node: 18.14.0
Package Manager: npm 9.3.1
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 15.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.8
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.6
@angular/cli                    15.1.6
@angular/fire                   7.6.1
@schematics/angular             15.1.6
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.9.5
```

Lowering ts version to 4.7.4 is not possible - some dependencies need higher versions

I would really appreciate any help with this issue!!

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I am using Firebase 9 with Angular. I am importing -  import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app'; and using     provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)), to initialise my app but it is askign for AngularFireModule, which I thought was used in the previous version.

Comment: I downgraded to Angular 13 from 15. The only way I was able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You just imported the library in your app.module.ts but didn't use it.

You also have to initialize the AngularFireModule beforehand

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: In Version 9 don't we import - import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app'; and then use     provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)), to initialise the app?